# Julia - Printing or Writing in a file a Backslash in a String

Tags: string, julia, backslash

I need, in Julia to write in a file, a LaTeX command, here is a minimal example :

```
open("./file.tex", "w") do f
   foo::Int = 5
   # write(f, "$foo\hline \n")        - This is what I would like to do
   # write(f, "$foo \\ \n")           - This is another thing I want to do, and it works
   # write(f, "$foo \\\hline \n")     - My final goal is this -> 
                                        leads to ERROR: syntax: invalid escape sequence
end
```

You've understand what I want, I'd like to have a string with a backslash in it, but not as an escape character. 
This doesn't work :

```
julia> "\"  # Error
```

neither this

```
julia> "\\\hline"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write `"\\hline"` to get what you want. In general the rule is that two `\` get converted to one `\` in the resulting string, so `"\\\h"` is an error, because it gets parsed as `"\\"` and then `"\h"` and `\h` is an invalid sequence, but e.g. `"\\\r"` would be accepted as `\r` is a valid espace sequence (so actually you had luck that `\h` is invalid as it allwed you to spot the error).

Also this means that if you want to have *`something\\`+newline* in the output you have to write `""something \\\\\n""` (five `\` - four to get `"\\"` and fifth to get a new line with `\n`).

You can use a raw string literal to avoid having to escape `\` like this: `raw"\hline"` (but you loose the ability to interpolate then). . See https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/strings/#man-raw-string-literals-1 for a corner case with `\` at the end of the string.

You might also be interested in this package https://github.com/stevengj/LaTeXStrings.jl if you work with LaTeX a lot.